# Spinner Item Selected not working Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have implemented an android spinner widget which is working fine when I add an arrayList with fixed string values and set it to the spinner adapter but when it comes to get the data dynamically (web service) and added to the spinner by a for loop it is not working. The data is being populated to the spinner to the spinner in both the cases but not able to get the selected item from spinner while clicking on it.

OrderRequestActivity Class

```
    public class OrderRequestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private LinearLayout itemLinear;
    String token = "";
    CategoryModel categoryModel;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayList<String> categoryDataArrayList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_order_request);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        categoryDataArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        token = CommonUtilities.getPreference(this,"token");

        getCategoryWebService();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categoryDataArrayList);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Log.e("Token OrderRequest",token);

    }

    public void lookingItemClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(OrderRequestActivity.this,OrderExchangeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    private void getCategoryWebService(){
        WebServiceController.getResponse("GET", OrderRequestActivity.this, "order/categories", null, true,token, new WebServiceController.VolleyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                try {
                    Log.e("Response result",result);
                    categoryModel = new CategoryModel().response(result);
                    CommonUtilities.setPreference(OrderRequestActivity.this,"CategoryData",result);
                    for (int i=0;i<=categoryModel.getData().size();i++) {
                        categoryDataArrayList.add(categoryModel.getData().get(i).getCategoryName());
                        Log.e("CategoryName >> ",categoryModel.getData().get(i).getCategoryName());
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {
                try {
                    Log.e("Response Error",error);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + parent.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is because you are setting the adapter in onCreate() and just changing the categoryDataArrayList in onSuccess(). You need to notify the adapter about the change. call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). This should work :)

Comment: @Prashant.J shall I set the adapter inside onSuccess and notify there only?

Comment: Yes that will do the work :)

Comment: I hope I have answered your question? I forgot to add it as an answer and I have added as a comment :(

Comment: But @Prashant.J that solution you gave is not working buddy. By doing that not able click on spinner even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to notify the adapter that the list data has changed. Make `dataAdapter` a class member

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
```

and call `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside `onSuccess` after you update the list of items:

```
// NOTE: changed to i < size, not i <= size or you will get an array bounds exception
for (int i=0;i<categoryModel.getData().size();i++) {
    categoryDataArrayList.add(categoryModel.getData().get(i).getCategoryName());
}
dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```